# How to make UITextField become firstresponder using its tag field

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags, uitextfield, first-responder

I have several UITextfields, I am trying to set the first responder to be the first UITextField which its tag should equal 0.

This is how I am trying to achieve this in code

```
[[self.cutField viewWithTag:0] becomeFirstResponder];
```

But the problem being is that this UITextField never becomes the first responder.

Comment: can you try with tag greater than 0 ?

Comment: i just tried using 1 and 2 and it dose not work.. obviously as soon as i touch then textfield everything works correctly.. but yea.

Comment: Is the text field a subview of `self.cutField`?

Comment: 0 is default tag for any view. Just print `[self.cutField viewWithTag:0]`, probably this view is not your text field.

Comment: hey did you call the delegate method? if not do self.cutField.delegate=self;

Answer (score 3):

[self.cutField  becomeFirstResponder] should work

You don't need the subviews as the textfield is a UIView.

You may use it's parent view, such as in the controller class,

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
 [[self.view viewWithTag:0]  becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me, in the textFieldShouldReturn delegate method you can use the textField object specified in the delegate method with the tag of your textField which you want to resign.You can also use the object of the textField you want to resign([cutField resignFirstResponder]).

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [[textField viewWithTag:0] resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

if you are not using IB,you have to set tags to each of your textFields programatically.

Comment: This code works because `viewWithTag:` begins its search with the receiver. All views have a default tag of 0. So calling `[someView viewWithTag:0] will return `someView` as long as `someView` doesn't have some other specific tag. This is pointless.

Comment: But why would you call `viewWithTag:` here? Why not just do `[textField resignFirstResponder];`? The `textField` isn't going to have any text field subviews.

Comment: No. Calling `resignFirstResponder` will only resign the text field you call it on. Besides, only one text field can be the first responder anyway. There is NO need to use a tag in the code you posted in your answer.

Comment: hey maddy i know that,thats what i said in the above comment.But i answered to the question he wants to use the tag.

Comment: Using this code when the method is called textField is comming back as null when I log it.

Answer (score 1):

-viewWithTag: method returns UIView object so you need to cast its type explicitly:

```
    UITextField *yourTextField = (UITextField *)
    [self.view viewWithTag:0];

 // now set to first responder
  [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
[(UITextField*)self.cutField viewWithTag:0] becomeFirstResponder]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface TextInputVC ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField    *inputTextView;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.inputTextView                   = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 100)];
    self.inputTextView.backgroundColor   = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.inputTextView.delegate          = self;
    self.inputTextView.tag               = 1000;
    self.inputTextView.text              = self.fieldTextValue;
    [self.view addSubview:self.inputTextView];

    // [inputTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    [self showKeyboard];
}

-(void) showKeyboard {
    UITextField *textfield  = (UITextField *)[self viewWithTag:1000];
    [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Change UITextView to UITextField

Comment: @hussainShabbir : thks changed to UItextField